# how to find the Xpath for below given check box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYfIW.png)

Please tell me how to get the xpath for check box.

Comment: You need to share HTML code here instead of screenshot..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Chrome` browser - one easy way you can use:

1. Open the `Inspect` (or just click the F12 key)
2. Mark the element you need and right click on it (or just right click on the object (the check box) you are looking for)
3. Choose **Copy** ---> **Copy Xpath**

Answer (score 0):

I think the tshirt option is not public yet, did not get it in your site.I tried with shirts, looks like same dev pattern to me, let me know if the solution does not work.

```
<input id="Classic" class="facetChkBox" type="checkbox" value="brickstyletype:Classic" name=""/>
<label for="Classic"/>
```

This is the background html code.

As you already know, this is not the classic checkbox html code, so we need to create a xpath for this as shown below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@for='Classic']"))
```

from the point of code reusablity I would suggest a method like this:

```
public void clickOnCheckbox(String checkbox){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@for='"+checkbox+"']")).click();
    }
```

and call it using

```
clickOnCheckbox("Blousons");
```

In this way you can use the same code to click on different check boxes, and create a clean code.

to relate more to what I am saying you can go the url
https://www.ajio.com/women-shirts/c/830316016